# Is there anyway to connect to a WPA Enterprise Wi-Fi network with version 1.5 on a Motorola Backflip?

Tags: security, wi-fi

The only available security options when adding an new Wi-Fi network are:

- None
- WEP
- WPA Personal
- WPA2 Personal

I was hoping to connect to WPA Enterprise either by getting it added to the list, or finding a workaround/hack to do so.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1386

Short story; Android uses wpa_supplicant for its WPA support, so it can connect to WPA Enterprise, however the configuration app lacks the UI to configure wpa_supplicant for WPA Enterprise.

As a workaround, you can configure wpa_supplicant configuration files manually, try this: http://waipeng.blogspot.com/2009/08/howto-wpa-enterprise-on-android-htc.html